# Handling Failed Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management

This question is more of a sanity check rather than "please solve my problem". I've recently inherited some code for an application that was written over a couple of decades, by a number of different developers of varying skills. Consequently, trying to make sense of what the code is actually wanting to do is always a bit of a mission in itself.

Anyway, I came across this initialisation pattern time and time again where memory is dynamically allocated, and the result checked soon afterwards. Because this code is in both a stand-alone library and a GUI, the previous developers used a `_STANDALONE` macro to check this and handle the error accordingly:

```
double *myArray = (double *) calloc(length, sizeof(double));
if (myArray == NULL)
 {
      strcat(message1, "myArray");
#ifdef _STANDALONE
      fprintf(stderr, "%s %s\n", message1, message2);
#else
      MessageBox(Window, message1, message2, MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
#endif
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

*Note: You can assume `message1` and `message2` contains a string saying "failed to allocate memory for varible..." and is big enough to have extra gubbins appended to it.*

Here comes the sanity check. The most likely reason a memory allocation would fail is that the operating system didn't have any spare. Let's take a look at the error handling code, if we assume there is no more memory spare:

- the `fprintf` may or may not fail depending on the state of internal buffers. I don't know what the function looks like under the bonnet but I'm going to assume its memory requirements are minimal.
- I'm pretty sure the call to `MessageBox` would result in additional memory allocations because this results in GUI objects being presented on screen. Therefore, surely this would fail and so doesn't achieve what the developer intended.

In short, I suggest that this could be better handled but it's not so obvious the correct path to take.

Comment: Throw an exception, catch at the top level and log them? Or just call exit/abort.

Comment: "The most likely reason a memory allocation would fail is that the operating system didn't have any spare." not necessarily, rather "if the OS does not have enough free memory as was requested". it could be that `length` contains a rather large number, which could cause the allocation to fail but still the `fprintf` / GUI could still work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because `calloc` failed doesn't mean that the error handling paths will fail too.

- `calloc` possibly failed because the request was ridiculous.  For example, if `length * sizeof (double)` overflows, `calloc` should fail.  Or even perhaps the request is an unreasonable amount of memory in the first place even if there is no overflow.  In these circumstances, there might be plenty of free memory for use by `fprintf` or `MessageBox`.
- Without knowing the implementations of `fprintf` and `MessageBox`, you cannot know for certain whether they will require additional memory allocations.  Perhaps the system already reserved some memory for them for the purpose of showing error messages in low-memory situations.

I wouldn't worry about `fprintf` and `MessageBox` failing. If your system truly does not have enough free memory to deal with `fprintf` or `MessageBox`, it's probably going to be freaking out in plenty of other ways.  Terminating in the face of such extreme memory pressure is pretty reasonable.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes, it certainly would be ridiculous to legimately call `calloc` with arguments that would result in integer overflow.  But there are plenty of ways to do it accidentally (e.g. one of the factors started off as a negative integer, one of the factors involved user input, one of the factors was simply an uninitialized variable...).  And that's one of the advantages of using `calloc` over `malloc`: so that it fails instead of allocating a buffer that's smaller than expected (which then could lead to buffer overflows).

Comment: There's no difference... neither calls could have knowledge whether the requested size is the right one...

Comment: Thank's for your answer @jamesdlin. Is there anything a responsible developer can do to check this (without looking at the implmentation) or just accept this as a risk? If so, could you add it to your answer?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath You know for certain that the requested size is invalid if an integer overflow occurred, and `calloc` fails instead of potentially allowing reading/writing out of bounds.  How is that not a difference?

Comment: @jamesdlin: I wasn't talking about that scenario, but the rest you mentioned ("But there are plenty of ways"). And honestly, relying on `calloc` catching the potential overflow sounds a quite desperate attempt to me... you're in real trouble if that's your last line of defense. You should hunt down these bugs with extensive unit testing and sanitizers...

Answer (score 0):

The big question here is the typical size of "length". In case the length regularly is very high (let's say 1MB and up) it's pretty safe to assume that you still have enough memory for a simple message box even if the allocation failed. (and the actual goal of the check is to protect against these very large allocations).

In case the array is usually small, you better don't show any boxes. (What you could do is to preallocate all necessary resources to show the window. not sure that's possible with a message box however).

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this problem is to pre-allocate some memory which will never be used.

When you run out of memory, you `free` this area, so hopefully your error handler will have enough memory to finish its job.